Convert number date/time to human readable date/time in Athena
I am using Hudi MoR for storing the data in AWS S3 Lake and using the Athena for querying. My data comes through kafka streaming.
I have a date column and time column in source db with below example values
date_col: 2024-08-16
time_col: 08:56:09

My kafka message gives the date and time values in bigint as shown below
date_col: 19951 (Represents the number of days since the epoch)
time_col: 32169000 (Represents the number of milliseconds past midnight, and does not include timezone information)

While querying from AWS Athena i want to cast/convert these values to the human readable values as shown above for source db.
Note: I don't want to do conversion in my streaming job

You can simply use date_add with basis of the epoch start (1970-01-01):
select date_add(
    'millisecond',   
    time_col, -- add time
    date_add('day',
       date_col, -- add days
       timestamp '1970-01-01' -- epoch start
    )) 
from data_table;

Which gives:
        _col0
---------------------
 2024-08-16 08:56:09

for your data
